# How to make sure the application is built with the latest class library

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task, sourcegenerators

I have a class library and an application project with a reference to the class library.

In the application project, I have a custom target which calls a custom target in the class library:

```
<Target Name="AppTarget" ...>
   ... // Custom task to generate some content used by the LibraryTarget in the library

   <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReferences)" Targets="LibraryTarget" SkipNonexistentTargets="True" />
</Target>
```

The custom target LibraryTarget generates some code based on that generated content, and the generated code is included in the compilation.

How do I make sure that the application is packaged with the class library built with the generated code?